# What's the quickest way to get Sharpness +1

Tags: monster-hunter-4-ultimate

MH4U is my first in the series and I'm still learning all the different skills.  It took me a while to figure out that Sharpness on armor doesn't give sharpness +1. Handicraft does.

So what is the earliest I can get sharpness +1?  It doesn't matter if it's full set or mixed set.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This set is the earliest possible, available at Caravan 5, without requiring any charms, and have 3 extra slots:

```
Nargacuga Helm
Gore Mail
Ceanataur Braces
Gore Faulds
Uragaan Greaves (or anything with Torso Inc)
```

Comment: Actually went with Pyritie's suggestion of Tetsu greaves, but thanks for clarifying.

Comment: Yes, hence the brackets.

Answer (score 2):

[Handicraft](http://kiranico.com/en/mh4u/armor/skill/handicraft) is a relatively common armor skill and a lot of armor tends to have it at least in small amounts. That said, it doesn't appear much in low rank armors and it will be a bit more difficult to build into.

The earliest it seems can get handicraft is by mixing [Ceantaur](http://kiranico.com/en/mh4u/armor?a=287,288,289,290,291) helm and vambraces, [Gore](http://kiranico.com/en/mh4u/armor?a=317,318,319,320,321) chest and faulds, and finishing with [Arc Greaves](http://kiranico.com/en/mh4u/armor/legs/arc-greaves). This will be the only active skill, though.

Granted, this doesn't take any gems or talismans into account. So you could get it a different way with the help of those. You can try using [Athena's ASS](http://forums.minegarde.com/topic/7348-athenas-ass-for-mh4g-and-mh4u/) to help get a better build for you, as Kuranico's doesn't take gems and talismans into account.

Comment: This is slightly incorrect, you can get Sharpness +1 even earlier by using a leg piece with Torso Up, such as the tetsucabra greaves.